# How to determine Rational Canonical Form given the following information about $8 \times 8$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have $c_A(x) = (x^2+1)^4$ and $m_A(x) = (x^2+1)^2$, denoting the characteristic and minimal polynomials respectively. Let $f = x^2+1$. I know my possible forms are:
$$C(f^2)\oplus C(f) \oplus C(f)$$ or $$C(f^2) \oplus C(f^2)$$

I am also told that $\mathrm{rank}(f(A)) = 4$, but how do I use that information to determine which RCF (Rational Canonical Form) to use.

Answer (score 1):

From the proof of the RCF Theorem we know that in the first case our vector space $V$ may be assumed to be $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X)^2)\oplus\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))\oplus\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$, with the linear transformation $\alpha$ (whose matrix is $A$) acting as multiplication by $X$.

Hence $f(\alpha)$ acts as multiplication by $f(X)$ and so kills the $4$-dimensional space $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))\oplus\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$; it also kills the $2$ dimensional subspace $(f(X))/(f(X)^2)$ of $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X)^2)$. That is, the nullity of $f(\alpha)$ is $6$ and the rank is therefore $2$.

Conclusion: if we are given that the rank of $f(A)$ is $4$ then the RCF is $C(f^2)\oplus C(f^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Clearly these two RCF have different ranks: if $r$ is the rank of $C(f^2),$ then $r\geq 1$ (why?) and the rank of the first one will be $r$, while the rank of the second one will be $2r$ (why?)

So what you have to do, is to compute explicitely $f(C(f^2))$ and its rank.